# How to show that the Laplacian is not closed?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, elliptic-pde

Let us define the Laplace operator $A:D(A)\subset L^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$ by setting $Au:=-\Delta u$ and $D(A):=H^2(\Omega)$ (without any boundary condition), where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain with smooth boundary. From Weyl's lemma, we can infer that this operator is closable. However, the proposition 4.1 in the paper, titiled "[Boundary value problems for elliptic partial differential operators on bounded domains](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123606004228)", shows that $A$ is not closed. The approach there is not direct and has to use the concept of "quasi-boundary triple".
I just wonder **if there is a simple, direct method** to show that $A$ is not closed.

Comment: In the one-dimensional case of $\Delta$ on a finite interval $[a,b]$, it is easy to see that there is a continuum of (proper) self-adjoint extensions beyond $H^2$, depending on choices of boundary conditions.

Answer (score 5):

In the multidimensional case the domain of the maximal operator associated to
$-\Delta$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ is given by 
$$
D_{\max}:=\{f\in L^2(\Omega):\Delta f \in L^2(\Omega)\},
$$
and here $\Delta f$ is understood in the sense of distributions. This space is larger than $H^2(\Omega)$ as e.g. all harmonic functions in $L^2(\Omega)$ belong to $D_{max}$, but these
harmonic functions are not necessarily in $H^2(\Omega)$ (since their weak derivatives may not be square integrable).

Now equip $D_{max}$ with the graph norm $\Vert f\Vert:=\Vert f\Vert_{L^2}
+\Vert\Delta f\Vert_{L^2}$. 
It is known that the space $C^\infty(\overline\Omega)$ is dense in $D_{max}$
and hence also $H^2(\Omega)$ is dense in $D_{max}$ with respect to the graph norm, but $H^2(\Omega)\not=D_{max}$ by the argument above. The maximal operator associated to $-\Delta$ coincides with the adjoint of the minimal operator defined on $H^2_0(\Omega)$ and hence the maximal operator is closed.
It follows that the closure of the Laplacian defined on $H^2(\Omega)$ is the maximal operator and that the Laplacian defined on $H^2(\Omega)$ is not closed.

In the one-dimensional case the situation is different: If $\Omega=(a,b)$, then the maximal domain $D_{max}$ coincides with $H^2((a,b))$, and hence
in this case the Laplacian $-\Delta=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ defined on $H^2((a,b))$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you very much. The argument is fine and acceptable. But could you give an example of a distribution that $u\in D_{max}$ but not in $H^2$? I need to explain to my students. So, an easy one is appreciated.

Comment: I think a harmonic function with the form $\frac{1}{|x-1|^\alpha}$ may work. Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer contradict the comment by @paulgarret under the question?